# How do I sign a dynamic library to allow access to keychains created by another signed executable?

Tags: macos, code-signing, keychain

I have an executable which runs as a root-level daemon (launched from /Library/LaunchDaemons) and a dynamic library that it loads. They are both signed with the same identifier and both need to access the same keychain. When I call `SecKeychainItemExport()` from code in the dynamic library I get the error code `-25308`. This translates to `errSecInteractionNotAllowed`...essentially a permissions problem.

If the daemon process is instead run from a terminal window as root then I am presented with prompts asking me: "{your process} wants to export key "privateKey" from your keychain. Do you want to allow access to this item?" Clicking Always Allow on these prompts allows everything to proceed without error. It seems that when the process is running headless it's unable to prompt so it simply fails with the `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` error.

I had assumed that if the executable and the library were both signed with the same certificate and same identifier then they would have equal access to resources like the keychain but I seem to be missing something.

For code signing, this is the command being run on the dynamic library:

```
codesign -s "$CertName" -i com.abc.xyz -r='designated => anchor trusted and identifier com.abc.xyz and certificate leaf[subject.O]="My Company" and certificate leaf[subject.CN]="My Company"' ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/library.dylib
codesign -dvvv ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/library.dylib
```

What needs to be done to the code signing to allow equal access between my executable and library?

Comment: How is this root-level daemon accomplished/set up/installed? (For example, by a /Library/StartupItems/ startup item, by a /Library/LaunchDaemons item via SMJobBless, or...?). When you say "...is instead run from a terminal window...", at what user-level are you running it at: the regular user level or are you using `sudo` or `su` to run it as root?

Comment: Edited the question to address comments about how the process is started (/Library/LaunchDaemons item) and how I ran it from the terminal window (as root).